# Bitcoin halving conflict? Is this a rumor

Tags: mining-reward, reward-schedule

Is there a conflict as to when the halving will occur and Bitcoin miner rewards become 12.5? Is is set in stone to happen this July or is it after a certain amount of blocks?

Answer (score 12):

It is exactly at block 420000.

When block 420000 will be mined is not certain, as the block mining process is random and influenced by hashrate variation.